# eloquent relation not working on live server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have two tables one is user and other is profile. one user can have one profile. This relation works perfectly on local server but when i upload it on live server the relations are not working not just user and profile but other relations also.
here is my laravel model code for profile and user.

```
class Profile extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['user_id','fname','mname','lname',
    'birthdate','country','address','phone', 'image'];

  protected $hidden = ['user_id'];

  public $timestamps = false;

  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
  }
}
```

User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'email_token'
  ];

  protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token', 'email_token'
  ];

  public function users(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'user_id');
  }
}
```

Here how i am trying to get profile data from login user in controller

```
Auth::user()->users->image
```

Comment: what error there?

Comment: (1/1) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: try as `Auth::user()->image`

Comment: results in null

Comment: test as Auth::user()->id   is it returns user id?

Comment: yes it return current user id

Comment: it means your code is running fine while your image column is null or url in image column have nothing to show that 's why its was returning null.

Comment: No sir, image column is not null it has value. an url

Comment: what it have inside?

Comment: "/profile/Avesh/DZAsnvtrtJ27dhJXmUwYJ6YbiPBuLCgH68BFEu0E.jpeg"

Comment: please go on this path in your cpanel have you image there with same path and same name as well?

Comment: you can test in your browser as www.yourdomain.com/profile/Avesh/DZAsnvtrtJ27dhJXmUwYJ6YbiPBuLCgH68BFEu0E.jpe‌​g

Comment: ya that image is present

Comment: view this hope it will solve your problem https://devdojo.com/episode/laravel-user-image

Comment: @Avesh, try `Auth::user()->users()->image` because if you dont do in Login that Auth is User::with('users'), than `Auth::user()->users` is empty and you have to call `Auth::user()->users()` function to get the `users `data

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::users()

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution the problem was

```
 public function users() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
}
```

this should have been

```
 public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
}
```

changed from plural to singular.